# Left shift and cast to unsigned back to signed

Tags: c, types, casting, bit-manipulation

Can somebody explain why you would want to do the below? For sake of argument ErrorAssignment is also of type sint32

**Question:**

**What is the purpose of casting to unsigned, doing a left bitshift and then casting back to a signed datatype?**

- sint32 is a signed 32 bit integer
- uint32 is an unsigned 32 bit integer

---

```
ErrorAssignment = ((sint32) (( (uint32) DemandError) << 9))
```

**Edit 1: The above actually comes from a comparison that ultimately becomes a truth value. See the below code for a more complete description**

```
sint32 valueOutCompare;
uint8  aCompareValue;
Boolean isValueTrue;
sint32 positiveLimitValue = 50;
sint32 negativeLimitValue = -50;

isValueTrue = ( (valueOutCompare > ((sint32) (((uint32)positiveLimitValue<< 9)))
                 ||     ((valueOutCompare  < ((sint32) (((sint32) negativeLimitValue) << 9)))) );
```

Comment: It looks like was taken from somewhere in the middle of an actual question...

Comment: So what is your problem? Wht did you find out? What is **specifically** unclear? Why don't you use standard fixed-width types? What is your platform? What does your implemention specify for conversion unsigned to signed?

Comment: signed shifts are: right - implementation defined, left - UB. So the guy who wrote it just made sure to have bitwise left shift.

Comment: Actually left-shifting is only UB when the first operand is negative. @PeterJ_01

Comment: @alain so in general it is if you do not check the sign of the shifted object.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: signed left shifts are not UB in general. And right shifts are not implementation defined in general either. If you can ensure the value is not too large, there is no problem at all.

Comment: @Olaf bravo :). In general if one does not check for sign of the object, then cant safely use shift operands. And that is the reason of the cast to the unsigned. Context of the answer matters my friend. Otherwise any comment is just a nitpick

Comment: @Olaf, This is an embedded system. I don't know what the conversion from unsigned to signed should be. I've inherited this code, and I'm trying to understand why this is being done.

Comment: @ThomasJ: As the phrase implies, _implementation dfined behaviour_ has to be defined by the implementation. Read the documentation of your tool chain. If they don't, they are not compliant and you should cget a guarantee from the vendor if that is commercial. gcc for instance **does** have a page for this.

Comment: @PeterJ_01, So, going from signed to unsigned, I understand you lose your sign bit. I'm not sure I understand why that would work when you don't know if the value is positive or negative, which goes back to the question, of why you want to bitshift.

Comment: @ThomasJ: No, you don't "loose" the sign-bit. The value is just converted. This is well defined by the standard and effectively behaves like re-interpreting a two's complement representation of the signed value as an unsigned value. Truncation is implementation if both have the same width. On 2's complement architectures this will not require any additional instructions.

Comment: Added some clarification, hopefully my question is more clear now.

Comment: `((sint32) (((sint32) negativeLimitValue) << 9))))` The casts just don't make  sense. The code looks strange; why don't you just multiply with `1<<9`? Leave optimisations to the compiler. That way it is guaranteed to maintain the sign. You did not clarify anything. Ask the author this site is not for speculating about every "strange" (to not be offending to the author) code. Is that even C code?? `Boolean`??

Comment: I don't know who the author is. Yes, it is c, I've given you as much information as I have. I don't even know who the original author of the code is, and the people I work with that I have asked, so far don't know why it's done either. Lastly, I assumed it was a basic embedded code trick. I had no way of knowing before posting that there was anything strange about the code.